# Django Rest Framework ModelSerializers - Handling create and update

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-signals

I have some models in my Django database. Each model is created or updated through the DRF API. As a result, I have serializers (for every model) that handle the create, update and `partial_update` on the models.

A main part of the handling includes the following action:

```
def handle():
    if created:
        model.owner = request.user
        model.other_fields = other fields
        model.save()
    else:
        model.other_fields = other fields
        model.save()
```

Additionally, I need to create log entries whenever a model is saved, with `request.user`.

```
Log.objects.create(user=request.user, model=model, created=timezone.now())
```

I cannot use signals to create log entries, as the `post_save` signal does not have the request object.

How should I handle this?

- Should I create a custom signal and send it every time I create or update a model?
- Should I call a function in serializer's `create` and `update` to log the model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid using signals. The best approach is

**OPTION 1**

- call a function in serializer's create and update to log the model

But, do it using a mixin.

```
class LogSerializerMixin(object):

   def create_log(self):
       //do logic over here
       // get your request over here using self
       // get your model using self.instance
       Log.objects.create(user=request.user, model=model, created=timezone.now())
```

Then in your serializers

```
Serializer1(LogSerializerMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self):
        // creation logic over here
        self.create_log()

    def update(self, data):
        // update logic over here
        self.create_log()
```

Another serializer.

```
Serializer2(LogSerializerMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self):
        // creation logic over here
        self.create_log()

    def update(self, data):
        // update logic over here
        self.create_log()
```

**OPTION 2**

- Rewrite save model method and add log creation logic over there.

Comment: Option 1 looks great! Option 2 won't possible as the model does not have access to the request.

Comment: @levi: Could you explain why the OP (or "we") should avoid using signals? Do you suggest to avoid them in general, or just for this specific case?